# Preserve string typing when mapping json dates to a Typescript class property

Tags: json, angular, typescript, iso8601

I have an Angular2 application that is using a service to fetch data from a Web Api like this:

```
export class Customer {
    public customerId: number;
    public customerName: string;
    public dateOfbirth: Date;
}

public getCustomer(customerId: number): Observable<Customer> {

    let url = this.config.baseUrl + "http://BlahBlah/Customer/Get/" + customerId;

    return this.http
        .get(url)
        .map(res => res.json());

}
```

The service returns the object with dates in ISO 8601 format like this:

```
customerId: 1
customerName: "John Wilkes"
dateOfBirth: "1998-11-04T00:00:00"
```

The problem is that dateOfBirth is being converted to a string rather than a `Date` type despite it being declared as a `Date` in the Customer class declaration. How can I get this to be converted to a `Date` type as default behaviour without having to manually convert them in code?

Comment: `new Date(res.dateOfBirth)`

Comment: To be sent over the wire, the `Date` has to be serialized one way or another. I would use a number, the Unix Epoch in millis ( `Date.getTime()`), to avoid any timezone issue

Comment: I was hoping to avoid manually trying to convert each data that I get back from the server. thinking about this more the issue is with the RxJs map function. map seems to handle numbers and Booleans without a problem but is not recognising and preserving dates.